# SpringBoot; Can we use @Value in Java Enums

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

Is it possible to use @Value("${myapp.token.key}") in an Enum class?

Is it a good practice to use @Configuration or @ConfigurationProperties in an Enum class?

-- JK

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not. The purpose for an Enum is to give us mapped data (fixed set of values) with limited scope. If we would to use `@Value` in Java enums, it would take the purpose of the enum away in the first place.

The same goes for `@Configuration`, we do that when we want to inject instances in Spring's container. That doesn't make any sense for enums.

If you post the actual reason for why you were trying to do that, we may be able to point you in the correct direction / solution.

Comment: Thanks @Alessandra. Yes that make sense and hence my question, since I had a doubt about this approach.

Comment: To give more details: For e.g: I have to call 2 services - Order & Inventory, I have an Enum which has Order and Inventory. Also to have those respective URLs in the enum which needs to be read from the spring boot resources properties file.

Comment: Hey @codegeek, sounds like you don't need an enum. Try injecting a property class in the container using the `@ConfigurationProperties`. Then use that to access your env vars (urls). Good luck.

Comment: Your `@ConfigurationProperties` can define a `Map<MyEnum, URI>`.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- and crabby, i was trying to use MyEnum.url like i have other runtime class type as well, but I got what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible*, but it's not *easy* and definitely not a good idea. Prefer a service that implements an interface equivalent to `Function<MyEnum, String>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class with static fields and default values like bellow

```
class EnumLikeClass {

  public static String key;

  @Value("${myapp.token.key:Default value}")
  public void setKey(String keyTemp) {
    EnumLikeClass.key = keyTemp;
  }

}
```

Now you can call like

```
EnumLikeClass.key
```

Comment: No you can't !  you can't inject @value into static field directly, won't work!

Comment: @shivarajan yes, it's wrong answer! It will return null if we're using with static fields

Comment: @shivarajan thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer with manual setter, which works properly